# For loop not returning all, omitting one <option>

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am typing in the 'add poll' module form textboxes, that I am creating
and the choice of poll answers I'm adding is Yes, No, Maybe.

No and Maybe are caught, but Yes is omitted which is the first answer?

I believe this is the problem line after much troubleshooting.

```
for ($i=1; $i <= $number; $i++ )
```

Once submitted (from error log):

> Database error with statement INSERT INTO db_fpollitems VALUES (NULL, 66, No, 1, 0). Error was: Unknown column 'No' in 'field list'
>
> Database error with statement INSERT INTO db_fpollitems VALUES (NULL, 66, Maybe, 2, 0). Error was: Unknown column 'Maybe' in 'field list'
>
> Database error with statement INSERT INTO db_fpollitems VALUES (NULL, 66, , 3, 0). Error was: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 3, 0)' at line 1

If I replace

```
"NULL, {$poll['id']}, {$polloptions[$i]}, $i, 0");
```

with

```
"NULL, {$poll['id']}, $i, $i, 0");
```

it comes back with obvious poll answers of 1.2.3.

Here is the code to troubleshoot.

```
if ($_POST['submit'] == "Submit" && $word_ok)
{
    $subject = safesql($_POST['subject'], "text");
    $post = safesql($_POST['article'], "text", false);
    $number = $_POST['numoptions'];
            
    $pollquest = safesql($_POST['question'], "text");
    $polloptions = $_POST['option'];
            
    $username = safesql($check['id'], "text");
    
    $sql = $data->insert_query("ftopics", "NULL, $subject, 0 , $username, $timestamp, $username, $timestamp, $type, $fid, 0");
    if ($sql)
    {
        $sql = $data->select_query("ftopics", "WHERE subject=$subject AND numviews=0");
        $topic = $data->fetch_array($sql);
        
        $sql = $data->insert_query("fposts", "NULL, $subject, $post, $username, $timestamp, {$topic['id']}, 0, 0");
        if ($sql)
        {
            $data->update_query("users", "numposts = numposts + 1, numtopics = numtopics + 1", "id='{$check['id']}'");
            
            if ($pollquest != "" && $number > 1)
            {
                $sql = $data->insert_query("fpolls", "NULL, {$topic['id']}, $pollquest");
                if ($sql)
                {
                    $sql = $data->select_query("fpolls", "WHERE topic_id = {$topic['id']} AND question = $pollquest", "id");
                    $poll = $data->fetch_array($sql);
                    for ($i=1; $i <= $number; $i++ )
                    {
                        $data->insert_query("fpollitems", "NULL, {$poll['id']}, {$polloptions[$i]}, $i, 0");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: mysql is not sql server

Comment: Have you done the basic debugging like `print_r( $polloptions )`? Array indexes start generally from zero.

Comment: "Database error with statement INSERT INTO db_fpollitems VALUES (NULL, 66, No, 1, 0). Error was: Unknown column 'No' in 'field list'".

You need to quote the 'No', if you intend to insert the value 'No' as a string. Otherwise MySQL will think you're referring to a column, as it says.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting literals without quotes, please try this insead:

```
"NULL, {$poll['id']}, '{$polloptions[$i]}', $i, 0");
```

your code should be like :

```
if ($_POST['submit'] == "Submit" && $word_ok)
{
    $subject = safesql($_POST['subject'], "text");
    $post = safesql($_POST['article'], "text", false);
    $number = $_POST['numoptions'];

    $pollquest = safesql($_POST['question'], "text");
    $polloptions = $_POST['option'];

    $username = safesql($check['id'], "text");

    $sql = $data->insert_query("ftopics", "NULL, '$subject', 0 , '$username', $timestamp, '$username', $timestamp, '$type', $fid, 0");
    if ($sql)
    {
        $sql = $data->select_query("ftopics", "WHERE subject='$subject' AND numviews=0");
        $topic = $data->fetch_array($sql);

        $sql = $data->insert_query("fposts", "NULL, '$subject', '$post', '$username', $timestamp, {$topic['id']}, 0, 0");
        if ($sql)
        {
            $data->update_query("users", "numposts = numposts + 1, numtopics = numtopics + 1", "id='{$check['id']}'");

            if ($pollquest != "" && $number > 1)
            {
                $sql = $data->insert_query("fpolls", "NULL, {$topic['id']}, '$pollquest'");
                if ($sql)
                {
                    $sql = $data->select_query("fpolls", "WHERE topic_id = {$topic['id']} AND question = '$pollquest'", "id");
                    $poll = $data->fetch_array($sql);
                    for ($i=1; $i <= $number; $i++ )
                    {
                        $data->insert_query("fpollitems", "NULL, {$poll['id']}, '{$polloptions[$i]}', $i, 0");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Gar Thank you, VERY APPRECIATED.
I changed only
'{$polloptions[$i]}'
And it submitted and refreshed to Poll correctly, only it still omits the first poll answer text. Will look into it and see if I can see why.